How to group identical elements of an array into a list of new arrays?
How can I group elements in an array which are equal and return these in separated arrays.
for example:
var array = [1, 5, 1, 4, 5, 5, 7]

The function should should return:
[[1 ,1], [4], [5, 5, 5], [7]]


A simple solution would be to sort the array using sort() and then iterate over the result, push the elements into a new array and start a new array whenever the current element is different from the last element.
